# Why by refreshing page localhost on browser bundle_client is stuck on pending status?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I made super simple ssr app on node + react. By refreshing page on localhost on browser (Chrome or Safari, no matter) bundle_client.js is stuck on pending status.

**GIT:**
https://github.com/antonkalik/ssr-app-chrome-issue

When I changed in src/server/index.js this:

```
  res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>${markup}`);
  res.end();
```

to this:

```
  res.status(200).end(`<!doctype html>${markup}`);
```

pending disappears.

What's wrong with that? Where I messed up?

As you can see in package.json I using react 17 and webpack 5. I want to keep it up to date.

**PROJECT STRUCTURE:**
[image]

**Screens from browsers**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call `res.end()` if you call `res.send()`. `res.send()` calls `res.end()` for you.

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.17.1/lib/response.js#L221